# Microsoft Teams - Deeplink to bot tab

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am currently building a bot for use in Microsoft Teams using the [BotBuilder SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-overview) and I'm having some trouble with Deeplinking from within the Teams application to a bot tab.

### Is there any way you can link to a static tab of a bot rather than just a channel tab?

I am aiming to have the bot send a message encouraging users to open one of the bot's static tabs by clicking a link/button sent in the conversation flow.

I have tried following the [Create deep links to a Microsoft Teams tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links) docs however it seems to only open one of the general channels not to a bot tab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can generate the deep link to the static tab. Try the url for deep linking to a static tab https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/28:" + BotId + "/" + TabEntityID + "?conversationType=chat; where BotId is the regeistered botId and TabEntityID is the entityId you have given in the manifest file.

This isn’t actually “public” knowledge. We really don’t have a problem with people currently using it, but we have plans to possibly change it so we don’t want it to be TOO wide spread.